# AngularJS not printing out Firebase data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have an AngularJS web app which is using Firebase and AngularFire. I noticed that in the controller, it is possible to print all database data from a given Database Factory (which returns a reference to all data). However  when printing data that is deeper than the root, that sub_data is undefined. Why does this happen?

```
function DatabaseFactory($firebaseObject) {
     // Bad practice to get all DB data, but just for purpose of this example
     return $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref());
 }

function MyCtrl(DatabaseFactory) {
     var data = DatabaseFactory;
     console.log(data); // Works correctly - prints all database data, even sub data
     console.log(data.user_profile); // Prints 'undefined' in console
 }
```

Data structure in Firebase is a simple JSON structure of users and orders:

```
/root
    -/ user_profile
    -/ user_order
    -/ order
```

The output of `console.log(data)`:

```
FirebaseObject {
    $$conf: ...
    $id: ...
    $priority: ...
    user_profile: ...
    user_order: ...
    order: ...
}
```

However if I print out each property individually, it does not print out any of the database objects:

```
var propValue;
for(var propName in data) {
    propValue = data[propName];
    console.log(propName, propValue);
}
```

Output:

```
$$conf
$id
$priority
$save
$remove
$loaded
$ref
$bindTo
$watch
$destroy
$$updated
$$error
$$scopeUpdated
$$notify
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a sub_data key under data. In your question you have mentioned it as sub-data ?

Comment: Yes, sub_data is there. Edited the original question to 'sub_data' for clarification

Comment: Can you show your data object? And what does DatabaseFactory return, is it an object or a promise?

Comment: Added example of data structure to the question

Comment: Can you show the console.log(data) output?

Comment: Added console output